# Compilacion de un proyecto libre de Github

Tags: c#, visual-studio

estoy intentando compilar con Visual Studio un proyecto de código abierto de GitHub pero al intentarlo me da unos cuantos errores...
Estoy acostumbrado a hacer cosillas en VS pero no tan gordas como esta y no se realmente que puede estar pasando

Me gustaría, con tiempo, ver si puedo quitar opciones de ese software, y volver a compilarlo, lo digo porque se que esta la versión ejecutable, sin necesidad de andar compilando nada, pero mi idea es partir de la solución de VS y poco a poco recompilarla conforme voy editando/modificando cosas.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

La solución esta en el siguiente enlace

[Enlace GitHub](https://github.com/treeDiM/StackBuilder)

Error al inicial la solucion por primera vez;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos

EDICION;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cuales son los errores?

Comment: En los errores marca proyectos de wix, prueba a instalar la extensión de wix de Visual Studio http://wixtoolset.org/ Si ya las tienes instaladas y aun así marca error, igual la solución que intentas abrir se hizo en una versión mas reciente que tu versión de Visual Studio.

Comment: Gracias @Luis, he instalado las extensiones de Wis para mi VS pero siguen saliendome los errores... hacen referencia a una .dll no encontrada, la verdad es que siendo una solución completa crei que tendria todo para funcionar, de hecho, se supone que esta abierta para poder modificarla. No obstante soy muy novato en el tema y posiblemente este haciendo cosas mal. Los errores a los que me refiero los actualizo en el hilo principal. Por cierto, lo he probado con dos PCs con VS recien instalado :D

Answer (score 1):

Si analizas las rutas y las buscas en el repositorio

[StackBuilder WIX](https://github.com/treeDiM/StackBuilder/tree/master/Sources/WIX)

lo que quiere construir es el instalador de la aplicacion, tienes que agregar la extension para que se cree los template de este tipo de proyectos

[WiX Toolset Build Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WiXToolset)

Lo mismo sucede con el del `ExternalAddIn`

Tambien puedes hacer que no compiles estos proyectos ingresando al `Configuration Manager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

accedes a esa opcion desde el menu del solution explorer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]